# How to set one div to be always on top of another div

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in CSS and HTML. This is what I am trying to achieve, a progress bar with text label on top of the progress. The position of the texts are fixed, the name is always on the leftmost part while the unit is always on the rightmost. I need multiple duplicates of this progress bar.

[image]

I was able to achieve the correct layout with only one copy.

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.stats-display-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: #86fffb1f;
}

.stats-progress-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #00586199;
}

.stats-progress {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #03d5ff;
}

.stats-label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 16px;
  color: #606060;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.stats-unit {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 14px;
  right: 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="view_container">
  <div class="stats-display-container">
    <div class="stats-progress-container">
      <div class="stats-progress"></div>
      <div class="stats-label">Temperature</div>
      <div class="stats-unit">80°C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

However, If I duplicate a copy of the group of divs, the result became this.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.stats-display-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: #86fffb1f;
}

.stats-progress-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #00586199;
}

.stats-progress {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #03d5ff;
}

.stats-label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 16px;
  color: #606060;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.stats-unit {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 14px;
  right: 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="view_container">
  <div class="stats-display-container">
    <div class="stats-progress-container">
      <div class="stats-progress"></div>
      <div class="stats-label">Temperature</div>
      <div class="stats-unit">80°C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stats-progress-container">
      <div class="stats-progress"></div>
      <div class="stats-label">Humidity</div>
      <div class="stats-unit">50</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

So, I have to change the `top` value of the style of the texts to around 48px to get the correct result. But isn't a good solution because the number of progress bar that I am going to display is dynamic.

I don't understand why the x and y position of the second copy of the texts the same with the first copy? I mean they belong to different parent div. I thought absolute positioning will be with respect to its parent div only. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to make the text behave RELATIVE to your `.stats-progress-container`.

You do that by adding the `position: relative` to that container div.
The ABSOLUTE position value of your `.stats-label` label will look to the first parent (if any) with the RELATIVE position

And then, you can tweak the text to be centered to that div again, but I think you can figure that one out on your own. (I tweaked it in the snippet, it has to do with the `top` attribute)

For more info on position relative, see [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.stats-display-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: #86fffb1f;
}

.stats-progress-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative; /* YOUR FIX */
  margin: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #00586199;
}

.stats-progress {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #03d5ff;
}

.stats-label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 16px;
  color: #606060;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.stats-unit {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 6px;
  right: 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="view_container">
  <div class="stats-display-container">
    <div class="stats-progress-container">
      <div class="stats-progress"></div>
      <div class="stats-label">Temperature</div>
      <div class="stats-unit">80°C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stats-progress-container">
      <div class="stats-progress"></div>
      <div class="stats-label">Humidity</div>
      <div class="stats-unit">50</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.stats-display-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: #86fffb1f;
}

.stats-progress-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #00586199;
  position: relative;
}

.stats-progress {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #03d5ff;
}

.stats-label {
position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 16px;
    color: #606060;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.stats-unit {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="view_container">
  <div class="stats-display-container">
    <div class="stats-progress-container">
      <div class="stats-progress"></div>
      <div class="stats-label">Temperature</div>
      <div class="stats-unit">80°C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stats-progress-container">
      <div class="stats-progress"></div>
      <div class="stats-label">Humidity</div>
      <div class="stats-unit">50</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That ok

Comment: You added top twice to your label div, that is not very nice :) Like the way you handled it though

Comment: I sorry, i forget delete it when edit code. Now it edited

Comment: It is alright I guess, I just point it out to sharpen your "neat" skills.

Answer (score 1):

1. You didn't apply [Position Relative](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) to the container.

The best solution to this kind of `position` problem is to put them in a `div.stats-progress-container`(`position relative`) and then apply the `position absolute`. and then you can use `top right bottom left`.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.stats-display-container {
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: #86fffb1f;
}

.stats-progress-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #00586199;
}

.stats-progress {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #03d5ff;
}

.stats-label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 16px;
  color: #606060;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.stats-unit {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="view_container">
    <div class="stats-display-container">
        <div class="stats-progress-container">
            <div class="stats-progress"></div>
            <div class="stats-label">Temperature</div>
            <div class="stats-unit">80°C</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stats-progress-container">
            <div class="stats-progress"></div>
            <div class="stats-label">Humidity</div>
            <div class="stats-unit">50</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` to `.stats-progress-container`. This will make `absolute` position be relative to that element.